# How to address views inside a fragment?

Tags: java, android, tabs, spinner

I'm sorry for my ambigous question title. I'll try to clarify my issue.
I've tried running this code to populate my spinner:

```
public void UcitajPromenljive(int id)
{
    if(id==0)
    {
        //#SPISAK
    }
    if(id==1)
    {
        //#PRETRAGA
        try
        {
            Spinner oblasti = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerOblasti);
            ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.oblasti, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            oblasti.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
        catch(NullPointerException e)
        {
            Log.e("LOAD_TAG", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    if(id==2)
    {
        //#OSTALO
    }
}
```

Sure enough, I did get a NPE, but I've found in a similar question that the problem is in the first line of the code. My application has three different tabs, that have been materialised as Fragments. So when I run findViewById(R.id.spinnerOblasti) the application returns NPE because my layout has only ActionBar and one Relative Layout as its property, and the Relative Layout is populated via

```
class MyTabListener implements ActionBar.TabListener
{
    public android.app.Fragment fragment;
    private Toast lol;
    public MyTabListener(android.app.Fragment fragment)
    {
        this.fragment = fragment;
    }

    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        ft.remove(fragment);
        lol.cancel();
    }
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        lol = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), tab.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        lol.show();
        ft.replace(R.id.okvir, fragment);
        UcitajPromenljive(tab.getPosition());
    }

    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

    }
}
```

So my question is - how do I address the Spinner which is a child of a certain .xml file that inflates one of the fragment (tabs)? Feel free to ask for clarification, I'm aware that this what I've wrote is somewhat confusing. Thanks in advance. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Store your fragment view for reference, i.e. in `onCreateView()` put the result view in fragments' global scope i.e.

```
protected View mFragementView;
```

and then when you need to find something within your fragment's layout do just:

```
mFragmentView.findViewById(....);
```

Example:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    protected View mFragmentView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView( LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState ) {    
        mFragmentView = super.onCreateView( inflater, container, savedInstanceState );   
    }

    public void UcitajPromenljive(int id) {
        View v = mFragmentView.findViewById( R.id..... );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but how would I address it in the function then?
EDIT: In the UcitajPromenljive function